# python find a nearby date - 3 cases

Tags: python, list, pandas, date, dataframe

I have the following two data frames.
df1:

```
date        customers
2017-10-09     8
2017-10-10     5
2017-10-11     4
2017-10-12     8
2017-10-13     9
2017-10-16     1
```

df2:

```
date         manager   prev_day    next_day   on_or_next_day
2017-10-10   george
2017-10-14   fred
```

I need a function that will complete the remaining three columns in df2. The logic for the columns is as such:
prev_day - the previous date that occurs in df1 before df2['date']
next_day - the next date that occurs on df1 after df2['date']
on_or_next_day - if df2['date'] is in df1 then put that or else the next date available in df1

Based on the example above the function should return the following for df2:

```
date         manager   prev_day    next_day     on_or_next_day
2017-10-10   george    2017-10-09  2017-10-11   2017-10-10
2017-10-14   fred      2017-10-13  2017-10-16   2017-10-16
```

As above you will notice that weekends are excluded for this example but in the real data frame there are days when the shop is shut etc so using BDay or something similar doesn't work you need to take the list of dates from df2.

Anything you are unsure about then please just ask as I have been battling this for ages now and can't get a very pythonic solution.

Comment: Getting a "pythonic solution" is not an end in itself. If you have any solution, that's fine, ask at [codereview.se] if it can be improved if you wish.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. To solve the problem for you (then it's off topic as too broad/opinion-based/useless for future readers (since the problem is not a recurring one))? Having a problem with some specific bit (then reformulate the question to ask about the bit and provide your task as a background detail)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it separately by using [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

```
df['NewDate']=df.date
```

next_day:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,df.drop('customers',1),on='date',direction='forward',allow_exact_matches =False).rename(columns={'NewDate':'next_day'})
    Out[136]: 
            date manager   next_day
    0 2017-10-10  george 2017-10-11
    1 2017-10-14    fred 2017-10-16
```

prev_day:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1,df.drop('customers',1),on='date',direction='backward',allow_exact_matches =False).rename(columns={'NewDate':'prev_day'})
Out[138]: 
        date manager   prev_day
0 2017-10-10  george 2017-10-09
1 2017-10-14    fred 2017-10-13
```

on_or_next_day:

```
   pd.merge_asof(df1,df.drop('customers',1),on='date',direction='forward',allow_exact_matches =True).rename(columns={'NewDate':'on_or_next_day'})
Out[141]: 
        date manager on_or_next_day
0 2017-10-10  george     2017-10-10
1 2017-10-14    fred     2017-10-16
```